# Java Program reads prefix and suffix

Tags: java, string, char

I am looking for some code to read the last TWO letters AND the first TWO letters on a single word and see if they match. The words will always be in upper case. this is the code i have so far and i am quite bummed why this will NOT work! sorry for being a n00b :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String s;
    char[] a;

    int input=scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();
        for(int i=0; i<input; i++){
            a = scan.nextLine().toCharArray();


        if((a[0] == a[a.length -1]) && (a[1] == a[a.length])){
                System.out.println("MATCH");
            }else{
                System.out.println("DO NOT MATCH");
            }

        }

}
```

}

first thing i do is a FOR statement for how many times it runs if you were wondering..

Comment: Why are you converting to a `char` array? The `String` class has the method `substring()` for a reason.

Comment: Is this homework?  Tag it as such, please.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing this:

```
if((a[0] == a[a.length -1]) && (a[1] == a[a.length])){
```

with this:

```
if((a[0] == a[a.length - 2]) && (a[1] == a[a.length - 1])){
```

Arrays are 0-based in Java, so the last element is actually `.length - 1`.  (An array of length 3 will have valid indices of `[0, 1, 2]` - not `[1, 2, 3]`.)

---

Edit: 
However, since Brian has since upped the ante: I would propose one better, which doesn't require converting the String to a character array - or require creating any new Strings through the use of substring.

```
String str = scan.nextLine();
if((str.charAt(0) == str.charAt(str.length() - 2)) && (str.charAt(1) == str.charAt(str.length() - 1))){
```

---

Also, what happens if your String is less than 2 characters?  (You may want to check for this...)

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there - the bit you're missing is that array's are indexed from zero so the *last* element in the array is a[a.length-1] and the penultimate one is a[a.length-2]

Answer (score 1):

Converting to a `char` array is actually kinda silly.

```
String line = scan.nextLine();

if (line.substring(0,2).equals(line.substring(line.length() - 2)))
{
    // it matched ...
}
```

**Edit:** You'll note that I'm using both forms of `substring()` above. The first one takes a start and end index, while the second takes only the start index and extends to the end of the source `String`. Take special note that the two argument version's second argument is the index *after* the substring you want.

Comment: +1 I completely agree. The `substring()` method is the best option when doing things like this.

Comment: I have looked into this yesterday and was wondering how to do this method. This just looks amazing i will try it later today! :)

Comment: The only odd thing with `substring()` in Java IMHO is that you have to remember that the second argument is the index *after* the substring you want. e.g. to get the first two characters you give it `0` as the start index and `2` as the end index. Thinking about it though, I just remembered there's two versions; I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are boolean methods for string called startsWith- and endsWith, respectively, for the class string.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/